# Proving that the "French train distance" gives a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

Letting $d$ denote the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, I define the "French train distance" on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$
d_T (p,q) = \begin{cases}
d(p,q) & \text{ if $p,q$ live on the same ray from the origin} \\ 
d(p,0) + d(q,0) & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$
Here is my attempt at checking that $d_T$ is a metric. One thing I'm not fully sure is how many different lines through the origin I can have. Since these are only rays that start at the origin, I don't think I would be correct in my initial intuition that if I have two distinct lines, I have all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I can have points $p,q,r$ that don't lie on the same ray from the origin.

> Let $p,q,r \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We first check that $d(p,q) = 0$ if and only if $p = q$. Suppose that $p,q$ live on the same ray from the origin. Then $d_T (p,q) = d(p,q) = 0$ if and only if $p = q$, as $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose $p,q$ do not live on the same ray from the origin. Then
> $$
> d_T (p,q) = d(p,0) + d(q,0),
> $$
> which is equal to $0$ if and only if $d(p,0) = d(q,0) = 0$, which is true if and only if $p = q = 0$, as $d$ is a metric.
>
> Next we verify that $d(p,q) = d(q,p)$. If $p,q$ are on the same ray from the origin, we have $d_T (p,q) = d(p,q) = d(q,p) = d_T (q,p)$ since $d$ is symmetric. If not, we have
> $$
> d_T (p,q) = d(p,0) + d(q,0) = d(q,0) + d(p,0) = d_T (q,p).
> $$
>
> Finally, we check the triangle inequality, namely that $d_T (p,q) \leq d_T (p,r) + d_T (r,q)$. Suppose $p,q,r$ are on the same ray from the origin. Then the required statement reduces to $d(p,q) \leq d(p,r) + d(r,q)$, which is true, since $d$ is a metric. Suppose now that $p,q,r$ do not lie on the same ray from the origin. Then
> \begin{align*}
> d_T (p,q) & = d(p,0) + d(q,0) \\ 
> d_T (p,r) & = d(p,0) + d(r,0) \\ 
> d_T (r,q) & = d(r,0) + d(q,0). 
> \end{align*}
> We then have
> \begin{align*}
> d_T (p,q) \leq d_T (p,r) + d_T (r,q) & \iff d(p,0) + d(q,0) \leq d(p,0) + d(r,0) + d(r,0) + d(q,0) \\
> & \iff 0 \leq 2d(r,0),
> \end{align*}
> which is true since $d$ is a nonnegative function. Suppose now that $p$ and $q$ lie on the same ray from the origin, but $p$ and $r$, and $r$ and $q$, do not. Then
> \begin{align*}
> d_T (p,q) & = d(p,q) \\ 
> d_T (p,r) & = d(p,0) + d(r,0) \\ 
> d_T (r,q) & = d(r,0) + d(q,0)
> \end{align*}
> By the triangle inequality and symmetry of $d$, we get
> \begin{align*}
> d_T (p,q) & = d(p,q) \\
> & \leq d(p,0) + d(0,q) \\
> & \leq d(p,0) + d(0,r) + d(r,q) \\
> & \leq d(p,0) + d(0,r) + d(r,0) + d(0,q) \\
> & = (d(p,0) + d(r,0)) + (d(r,0) + d(q,0)) \\
> & = d_T (p,r) + d_T (r,q). 
> \end{align*}
> Suppose now that $p,r$ live on the same ray from the origin but $p,q$ and $q,r$ do not. Then
> \begin{align*}
> d_T (p,q) & = d(p,0) + d(q,0) \\ 
> d_T (p,r) & = d(p,r) \\ 
> d_T (q,r) & = d(q,0) + d(r,0).
> \end{align*}
> The statement is then reduced to showing that
> $$
> d(p,0) + d(q,0) \leq d(p,r) + d(q,0) + d(r,0),
> $$
> which is true if and only if
> $$
> d(p,0) \leq d(p,r) + d(r,0),
> $$
> which is true by the triangle inequality on $d$. Finally, suppose that $r,q$ lie on the same ray from the origin but $p,r$ and $p,q$ do not. Therefore, we have
> \begin{align*}
> d_T (p,q) & = d(p,0) + d(q,0) \\ 
> d_T (p,r) & = d(p,0) + d(r,0) \\ 
> d_T (r,q) & = d(r,q),
> \end{align*}
> so the triangle inequality amounts to showing that
> $$
> d(p,0) + d(q,0) \leq d(p,0) + d(r,0) + d(r,q),
> $$
> which is true if and only if
> $$
> d(q,0) \leq d(r,0) + d(r,q). 
> $$
> By the triangle inequality on $d$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> d(q,0) & \leq d(q,r) + d(r,0) = d(r,0) + d(r,q).
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, $d_T$ satisfies the triangle inequality and is indeed a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

How does this look? Am I correct that these are all possible cases? Was I able to "shorten" the proof that $d(p,q) = 0$ if and only if $p =q$ as I did by using the properties of the Euclidean metric?

Comment: Not an answer but possibly of interest: If $Y$ is a subset of a metric space such that any two points of $Y$ are connected by a path of finite length, then the infimum of the lengths of paths from $p$ to $q$ is easily checked to define a metric on $Y$. <> Fix points $p$, $q$, and $r$ arbitrarily, and let $Y$ be the union of three rays from the origin containing all three points. (Fewer rays may be needed, but pick three anyway.) The "roundhouse metric" is the resulting path-distance metric, hence _is_ a metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct and all the cases. You could have argued by symmetry that last case of the triangle inequality should follow from the penultimate one (switching $p$ and $q$). The use of the Euclidean metric is also perfectly fine.